# Recreating the line detail in shadows from The Wolf Among Us in blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, compositing-nodes, shaders

This is my first year of using blender so I don't have a lot of experience in blender at all.

I'm trying to recreate an effect that *Telltale* used in *The Wolf Among Us* for my short film.

I don't know what its called or how to describe it, so here is my attempt to explain it, You can see the detail from the painted textures in dark shadows. I added a picture so you can understand my horrible explanation.

[image: The Wolf Among Us]

I tried a few experiments with texture nodes and even mixing nodes in composting but I can't get the effect I want and I'm hoping someone will tell me if this is even possible or direct me into the right nodes and usage of them.

This is just a basic scene I created to figure out how it works. In the next image you can see exactly what I want to do, keep in mind this is created in Photoshop by combining two renders just for explanation purposes.

[image]

Unfortunately I can't add anymore photos and I'm not sure how to link my .blend file so I hope this is enough info to show what I want to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a lamp with a very small size.

Comment: Think you'll need to resort to renderlayer/compositing magic for this..

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood your original question.  I would try using a separate render layer with a pure white diffuse material override.  Then plug that into a *greater than* node in the compositor and use it to mix the main layer with an other layer.  I am working on a way to make that "other layer".

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast replies. I made a post on blender artist a few days ago and still no response, a lot of views but no responses.

Comment: I have tried to do it with render-layers and compositing but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly. Its really hard to find tutorials in this specific thing I want. I will try what @PGmath said tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Use [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blends.

Comment: I would try to add an emission shader for the details you want to be clearly visible in shadows, but I am not good with textures and materials

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to get that effect, but I believe it's referred to as "Cell shading". You may want to search a blender tutorial by calling it cell shading and I'm sure you'll find some results.

Answer (score 1):

This won't take care of all the effects you're looking for, but you'd be able to get some of the pattern to show up in darkness by the material shadeless.  That won't create the effect you point out in the shadows on the floor, but it would work for the pattern on the wall.